# Interfacing Nextion with Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nextion

I am having trouble interfacing my Nextion display via Raspberry Pi. I have a Nextion project that contains one text field called t0. And I want to change the text displayed from Raspberry.

Here is what I tried:

```
import serial
import time
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate =9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)

k=struct.pack('B', 0xff)
time.sleep(1)

command = 't0.txt=\"hello\"'
ser.write(command.encode()) 
ser.write(k)
ser.write(k)
ser.write(k)
```

I am certain that connections are OK hence it is not hardware related.
Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
command = 't0.txt=\"hello\"'
```

I changed the command line to this:

```
command = 't0.txt="hello"'
```

Works for me good luck.